# What is a word/phrase that means "old" without the "outdated" aspect to it?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to form a sentence like so:

> In this lesson, we're going to take a look at X, a __ technique that's used for developing applications.

The technique has been known over the past decade or so, but it's not "old" per se and it can still be used today. In fact, it is only very recently that X has been widely known about accepted as a technique to develop applications.

Is there a word/phrase that conveys the "old" aspect of the technique without giving the impression that it is "outdated" and doesn't hold relevance today?

Comment: **Classic** technique?

Comment: −1 Very basic question easily answered by any thesaurus at all. Also, there are other issues with the sentence, and filling in the blank does not fix them no matter what you fill it in with.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: What are the other issues? I'm not arguing that this isn't easy to find in a thesaurus, but the question doesn't seem structurally wrong to me.

Answer (score 4):

When you say something is ***established***, it implies that it is *proven and still valid* (old but not outdated).

> In this lesson, we're going to take a look at X, an ***established***
>   technique that's used for developing applications.

ODO:

> **[established](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/established)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** Having been in existence for a long time and therefore recognized and generally accepted.
>
> ‘Why this was not an already established practice is a mystery to
>   critics.’

Macmillan:

> **[established](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/established#established_3)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** having existed for a long time, and therefore recognized as good or
>   successful
>
> ***established*** procedures/methods/criteria

Comment: Traditional might work as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would use ***pre-existing***.  The Oxford Dictionary defines it thusly:

> ***[pre-exist](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pre-exist)***
>
> VERB
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>
> usually as adjective pre-existing
>
> 1. Exist at or from an earlier time.
>      *‘a pre-existing contractual obligation’*